# Calling "Ada.float_text_IO.get" from a package to read user input from the console

Tags: ada

I want to use Ada.float_text_IO.Get , in a packagefile created : (.adb)&(.ads) from a mainfile to read user input from the console using the procedure:

```
procedure Get(Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);
```

There is no example anywhere . Help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to learn what SO users expect questioners to keep in mind before asking!

Comment: Since the [top result](http://web.mit.edu/16.35/www/psets/sales_tax.adb)  from googling “float_text_io.get” includes example usage, I’d suggest you spend a little more time on research for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two alternatives: wrap the procedure or rename it.

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   package My_Float_Text_IO is
      procedure Get_1 (Item : out Float; Width : Ada.Text_IO.Field := 0);
      procedure Get_2 (Item : out Float; Width : Ada.Text_IO.Field := 0) renames Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get;
   end;

   package body My_Float_Text_IO is
      procedure Get_1 (Item : out Float; Width : Ada.Text_IO.Field := 0) is
      begin
          Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item, Width);
      end;
   end;

   F : Float;

begin

   My_Float_Text_IO.Get_1 (F);
   My_Float_Text_IO.Get_2 (F);

end;
```

Put specification code into .ads files and body cody (implementation code) into .adb files.
You can also just put one procedure or function in .ads and .adb file without package. You can also have a specification package without body package.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I understand better now :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete working example which includes a package specification (floatget.ads) and body (floatget.adb) and a separate program (mainfile.adb) to call the Read_Floats_From_Console function in the FloatGet package.

The [Ada 95 RM section *A.10.9 Input-Output for Real Types*](http://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-A-10-09.html) indicates Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get skips leading whitespace and parses a float literal value of various formats from a file, **optionally if you use the form without the `File : in File_Type;` argument then Get will read from the console.**

#### Contents of floatget.ads package specification:

```
-- floatget.ads
--
-- FloatGet package specification defining procedure to read floats
-- from console

package FloatGet is
   procedure Read_Floats_From_Console;
end FloatGet;
```

#### Contents of floatget.adb package body:

```
-- floatget.adb
--
-- FloatGet package body using Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get to read floats
-- from console

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;

package body FloatGet is

   procedure Read_Floats_From_Console is
      Val       : Float;
      Sum       : Float := 0.0;
      N         : Integer := 0;
   begin

   Put_Line("Enter float values, one per line. Press CTRL-D when done.");

   Read_Loop:
      loop
         exit Read_Loop when End_Of_File;

         begin
            Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Val);
         exception
            when Data_Error =>
               Put_Line ("ERROR: Invalid float format");
               exit Read_Loop;
         end;
         Put ("Read value = ");
         Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Val);
         Put (", ");
         Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Val, Fore => 3, Exp => 0);
         Put (", ");
         Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Val, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
         New_Line;
         Sum := Sum + Val;
         N := N + 1;
      end loop Read_Loop;

      Put_Line ("Number of values = " & Integer'Image(N));
      Put ("Sum of values = ");
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Sum, Exp => 0);
      New_Line;
   end Read_Floats_From_Console;

end FloatGet;
```

#### Contents of mainfile.adb:

```
-- mainfile.adb
--
-- Main program calls FloatGet.Read_Floats_From_Console
--
-- Compilation: gnatmake floatget mainfile
--
-- Usage: ./mainfile
--
with FloatGet;

procedure MainFile is
begin
   FloatGet.Read_Floats_From_Console;
end MainFile;
```

#### How to compile it... (tested with gnat 4.8.4, 4.9.3, 5.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
$ gnatmake floatget mainfile
```

#### Sample run illustrating several valid float values...

```
$ ./mainfile
Enter float values, one per line. Press CTRL-D when done.
1
Read value =  1.00000E+00,   1.00000,  1.00
-1
Read value = -1.00000E+00,  -1.00000, -1.00
42
Read value =  4.20000E+01,  42.00000, 42.00
-42
Read value = -4.20000E+01, -42.00000, -42.00
.3
Read value =  3.00000E-01,   0.30000,  0.30
-.3
Read value = -3.00000E-01,  -0.30000, -0.30
2.0e3
Read value =  2.00000E+03, 2000.00000, 2000.00
-2.0e3
Read value = -2.00000E+03, -2000.00000, -2000.00
-16#1C.#e-1
Read value = -1.75000E+00,  -1.75000, -1.75
2#.11#e6
Read value =  4.80000E+01,  48.00000, 48.00
... Press CTRL-D here ...
Number of values =  10
Sum of values = 46.25000
```

This example doesn't rely upon anything gnat-specific so should work with any Ada 95 compiler although I have no way to test with other compilers besides gnat presently.

**EDIT** Simplified to only read from console instead per OP's request.

Comment: if i understand you used this procedure :        

`procedure Get(File : in File_Type; Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);`

Thank for the code .

I was thinking of this one , when i wrote the post :

`procedure Get(Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);`

To do a get from a input by the user from the console.

Comment: I simplified the answer to use `procedure Get(Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);` to read from the console as requested, and removed the use of `procedure Get(File : in File_Type; Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);` which reads from a file.

Comment: Thanks @ linguanerd  = Your exemple was perfect :)